# Issue with nested Inner <ul> list style

Tags: css

Can you please take a look at [this demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/sQWE6/2/) and let me know how I can fix the left indent of the inner `<ul>` and get rid of the dropped gray area before the child red background?

```
<ul class="sidebar-navigation">
    <li>List 1
        <ul class="sidebar-inner-list">
            <li> <a href="#">Link</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Link</a> </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
    <li>List 2
        <ul class="sidebar-inner-list">
            <li> <a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
            <li> <a href="#">Link 2</a></li>
        </ul>
    </li>
</ul>

body{color:#fff;}
ul{list-style-type:none;}
li{background-color:#2d2d2d;}
li:hover{ background-color:#ccc;}
.sidebar-inner-list>li{ background-color:red; margin-left:-40px;}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/sQWE6/4/

```
ul { padding:0 }
```

Just remove the automatic padding from the list. I guess the real question here is why don't you just use `<div>`s? They don't have automatic padding, and you don't seem to want an actual list (list-style-type: none).

Comment: Thanks James, just one very small question! can you please also let me know why the <a> color also change to red for a second which user click on it (in the inner list) here is a sample http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/sQWE6/5/ can you please let me know howto stop it?

Comment: Anchors have automatic coloring applied to. You can set it with `a {color:#00f}` if you don't want it to turn red.

Answer (score 1):

The `ul` list items has a `padding-left` by default, remove this and you should be good.

```
.sidebar-inner-list{
    padding-left:0;
}
```

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/39james/sQWE6/3/)**